# Undocumented ActiveRecord bang methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Is there a reason why ActiveRecord's bang methods are public, but not documented nor mentioned anywhere?

For example, `where!`, `order!`, `limit!` and others are all public and used by their non-bang counterparts.

I understand that they change the query object instead of its clone (and caution is necessary), but so do other bang methods, which are usually very well-documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They want to keep the API to be immutable, see the comments on this commit:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8c2c60511beaad05a218e73c4918ab89fb1804f0

And as for all undocumented methods (with `# :nodoc:`), they are part of the private API.
You should not use them as they could be removed without a warning.

hth

Comment: Thanks. This is the accepted answer now since it provides insight into rationale behind introducing the bang methods.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I'm not a RoR contributor, so if there is some RoR specific reason to it, I don't know.

As you said, they are wrapped by their non-bang counterparts. The `where` method for example checks if the method has the correct number of arguments and applies a the current scope to it. Moreover it provides the polymorphic behavior outlined in the documentation.

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4c0d6680ee011b822e6beaa1ee84f835e89550a1/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L550

My impression is that they are this way for abstraction reasons. The bang methods implement a lower level of functionality, while the non-bang methods provide a more user-friendly interface. As to why they are not documented but are public, I think the library authors wanted to provide the option to use them if you *really* know what you're doing.